# Cache Key strategie for large amount of data

Tags: performance, caching, scalability

I have aprox 3MB of information that is very hard to produce. It's a combination of join-querying some very big tables and heavy processing after the query is done. To top that off, the resulting info is read frequently (4-10 times per minute per client resulting in 3000 for all clients).

Should I store that info on the cache under a single key or should I break it and retrieve the N pieces every time i need it?

Details:
- I don't think that this is a "opinion-based question" because it is possible to prove with code that there's a better/worse scenarios
- I can't pre-emptively know which "shard" will contain the info i need... think of it as bank statements where a bank manager can look for both "transfers" and "$1400.00"... therefore i have to retrieve the whole thing for further filtering/sorting
- The data is not flat, but it's not **that** nested. Most of the items (about 70% are only 2 lvl, and the rest goes 3 lvls)
- I'm using Redis as caching server, and c# - Asp.Net MVC 4
- Filtering is single-sourced and applied on 4 fields (single search box that tries to match the value on 4 fields).
- Sorting is always by date

Comment: This sounds like a classic analytical process / data warehouse situation.  Can the resulting data be stored back in one or more denormalized database tables, or does it absolutely need to be cached in memory?

Comment: @KarlWenzel i'd say that cached in memory is way more performatic than any database solution due to the frequency of data access... raw estimative points to over 3000 access per minute

Comment: Without a database query engine to handle the optimizing and caching of all the filtering/sorting, then perhaps you could build your own indexes?  Maybe you have a code library that supports virtual data tables in your code?  What does your data look like; is it a flat table with a lot of fields, or is there a lot of nesting?

Comment: @KarlWenzel it's not flat, but it's not *that* nested... it goes up to 3 levels down, but there are not a lot of nested items...

Comment: OK, I have a meeting in a few minutes, but I'll come back to this.  In the meantime maybe somebody will see these comments and suggest something.  You might consider putting these additional details into your original question, along with how many filter/sort parameters you expect and what language / web platform you're using.

Comment: Well, I said that I'd come back to this, but you specify that you are using Redis, and I don't have enough experience with it to make a good answer. Maybe you could store each record with a key that combines the 4 searchable fields?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I store that info on the cache under a single key or should I break it and retrieve the N pieces every time i need it?

You need to take into consideration:

- what is the maximum object size you can cache (e.g. 1MB default `max_item_size` for memcached, but 512MB for redis string type)
- what actually makes sense for your workload (e.g. splitting in N pieces; would you use the individual pieces at all?)

> To top that off, the resulting info is read frequently (4-10 times per minute per client resulting in 3000 for all clients).

Based on this statement alone, my interpretation is that the **same** info is returned 3000 times. So for a single key, that would be 3000 cache requests, for N pieces, that would be N * 3000 requests. It's already easy to see which one is more expensive. Plus the computation time needed to combine the N pieces.

You may be able to do both:

- let your clients' requests use the single key.
- let your server-side use N cache keys, and reuse existing intermediate results where possible, combine them and store the result using the single key.